# disable tooltip for points that have a flag

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a highstock chart which has some of the points flagged with a circle. All the points in the chart have a tooltip as you hover over the chart.

However the tooltip for the points that have a flag should be one from the flag. I've been trying to see if highstock has an API through which I can say whether tooltip should be displayed on not based on the condition that the point has a flag or not. However, I'm stuck on how to find if a point has a flag or not.

Here a fiddle of my example : http://jsfiddle.net/ulhas87/WSDza/

```
{
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: 'USDtoEURexchangerate'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Exchangerate'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(){
            console.log(this);
            if(this.point){
                //if this point has a flag then return false 
                //else return the tooltip for this point 
                return this.y;
            }else{
                //this is a flag - hence return the flag tooltip
                return this.y;
            }
        },

    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'USDtoEUR',
            data: data,
            id: 'dataseries',
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 4
            },
            followPointer: false
        },
        {
            type: 'flags',
            data: [
                {
                    x: Date.UTC(2011,
                    1,
                    14),
                    title: '',
                    text: 'Shape: "circle"'
                },
                {
                    x: Date.UTC(2011,
                    3,
                    28),
                    title: '',
                    text: 'Shape: "circle"'
                }
            ],
            onSeries: 'dataseries',
            shape: 'circle',
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            y: -4,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    fillColor: '#395C84'//darker
                }
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function(){
                        console.log(this);
                    }
                }
            },
            zIndex: 10
        },
        {
            type: 'flags',
            data: [
                {
                    x: Date.UTC(2011,
                    2,
                    10),
                    title: 'C',
                    text: 'Shape: "flag"'
                },
                {
                    x: Date.UTC(2011,
                    3,
                    11),
                    title: 'C',
                    text: 'Shape: "flag"'
                }
            ],
            color: '#5F86B3',
            fillColor: '#5F86B3',
            onSeries: 'dataseries',
            width: 16,
            style: {
                //textstylecolor: 'white'
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    fillColor: '#395C84'//darker
                }
            },
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#000000'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your cherries are not the same as you are using for a flags. See updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/WSDza/3/

Also, I advice to set lower `hideDelay` to observer that point doesn't have tooltip.